# difficulty to correct

Tags: letter

the converted version. there must be one space between letters and two spaces between words. if the symbol is not possible to be converted into english (not in morse) there can be "#"

```
this version does not work.. ((( 
sign_eng = {'.-': 'a', '-...': 'b', '-.-.': 'c',
                  '-..': 'd', '.': 'e', '..-.': 'f',
                  '--.': 'g', '....': 'h', '..': 'i',
                  '.---': 'j', '-.-': 'k', '.-..': 'l',
                  '--': 'm', '-.': 'n', '---': 'o',
                  '.--.': 'p', '--.-': 'q', '.-.': 'r',
                  '...': 's', '-': 't', '..-': 'u',
                  '...-': 'v', '.--': 'w', '-..-': 'x',
                  '-.--': 'y', '--..': 'z', '-----': '0',
                  '.----': '1', '..---': '2', '...--': '3',
                  '....-': '4', '.....': '5', '-....': '6',
                  '--...': '7', '---..': '8', '----.': '9'
                  }

text = input("Enter your Morse code here: ")
text_words = text.split('   ')
words = ''
for text_word in text_words:
    text_letters = text_word.split('  ')
    letters = ''
for text_letter in text_letters:
    if text_letter in sign_eng:
        text = words + str(sign_eng[text_letter])
    if text_letter not in sign_eng:
        text = words + "#"

    result = "".join(words)
    print(result)`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: convertion from morse to english

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

words = words + str(sign_eng[text_letter])

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the code. Comments mark changes made:

```py
text = input("Enter your Morse code here: ")
text_words = text.split('  ')  # 2 spaces, not 3
words = []  # a list instead of ''
for text_word in text_words:
    text_letters = text_word.split(' ')  # 1 space, not 2
    letters = ''
    for text_letter in text_letters:  # nest loop to process  all `text_words`s
        if text_letter in sign_eng:   
            text = str(sign_eng[text_letter])
        if text_letter not in sign_eng:
            text = "#"
        letters += text  # update letters
        
    words.append(letters)  # update words list
    
result = " ".join(words)  # join words with a space
print(result)
```

```
Enter your Morse code here: .... . .-.. .-.. ---  .-- --- .-. .-.. -..
hello world
```

Here is a more concise version:

```py
text = input("Enter your Morse code here: ")
text_words = text.split('  ')
words = []
for text_word in text_words:
    word = "".join(sign_eng.get(letter, "#")
                   for letter in text_word.split(' '))
    words.append(word)
result = " ".join(words)
print(result)
```

and there's still room for improvement

Comment: Yes, that is also covered. Unless I'm not getting what you mean. `.... . .-.. .-.. ---+` is converted to `hell#`.

Comment: if the symbol is not possible to be converted into english (not in morse) there can be "#" (not in the end of all text).